# Retain Active Class on Bootstrap 3 Navbar Links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm aware there are similar posts on this issue, but I just cannot get any of the solutions to work for me.

I want to change the colour and background colour of the menu link for the current page the user is on.  But, when I style the active class with a 'working URL' the style is not retained.

If I use a hash (#) for the URL instead the background colour changes how I want, I presume because the page is not reloading.

I have tried lots of JS and JQuery solutions, but I cannot get any to work for me.

The below CSS is always enough to do the job for Wordpress Bootstrap Navs, but the active class is being added by Wordpress Nav Walker.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
color: #fff;
background-color: #000;
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:active, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(91,179,0)), to(rgb(56,141,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    color: #fff;
}    

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(91,179,0)), to(rgb(56,141,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    color: #fff;
}  

.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(91,179,0)), to(rgb(56,141,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(91,179,0)), to(rgb(56,141,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    color: #fff;
}  

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(91,179,0)), to(rgb(56,141,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(91,179,0)), to(rgb(56,141,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: -o-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(91,179,0,1), rgba(56,141,0,1) );
    color: #fff;
}



</style>

<script>

</script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>


<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> &nbsp; </a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              <li><a href="/about-us.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about-us.html">Contact</a></li>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
        </p>
      </div>


    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!--  Jquery  -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so in your URL you give a HEX color code that you want to use as background? Or you want to have a certain style when `../../components/**#navbar**` exists in URL?

Comment: Tried hex colour, no change; but, worth a try - thanks. Not sure what "Or you want to have a certain style when ../../components/**#navbar** exists in URL" means.

Comment: No, I was trying to understand what you want - haven't tell to try anything yet

Comment: If you know when the user is on you can simply add an `.active` class to `navbar` with some styles and should work - but I was confused about URL part

Comment: This is what I mean regarding the URL: If I use <a href="#"> the background colour change works, but if I use a live URL like <a href="about-us.cshtml"> and navigate away from the current page, the new page does not retain the active class.

Comment: Well, when you use # it means that your link it's an anchor to an element within that same page

Comment: you need a way to send info across pages when navigating, to know that user is online, something like `/url/top/page?isOn=true` and in your new linked page before rendering you need to check the value of `isOn`

Comment: I see you use ASP - so you can do something like what I've said, and add a class with condition like: <nav class="navbar <asp if(GET['isOn']==true) output "className" asp> I don't know .NET but just an idea

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried over righting the ".navbar-nav>.active>a:focus" using your own custom class as shown below or if you are allowed use "!important" try with it.

eg: .custome-class.navbar-nav>.active>a:focus

Regards,
Sijo Jose